# Dragon Age 2 - What to do with Bethany?

Tags: dragon-age-2

Hi I've finished the game once already as a mage, and have restarted as a warrior. I was wondering what I should build Bethany towards being. With Carver it was easy to make a choice given the gigantic sword he start off carrying, but with a mage you can take them in so many different directions.

If I presume that Anders will be a healer and Merrill will be my hexer/damage dealer, what do I do with Bethany?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SPOILER WARNING**

---

> It doesn't matter much because no
>  matter what you try you lose her after
>  act 2.
>
>  If she went with you into the Deep
>  Roads, she'll get infected by
>  Darkspawn corruption and die unless
>  Anders is in the party to make her a
>  Grey Warden (causing her to leave with
>  the other Wardens); if she didn't then
>  you get back to Kirkwall just in time
>  to see her getting carried off to the
>  Circle by the Templars, and you won't
>  see her again until near the very end
>  of the game.

Comment: NP. Sorry about getting the spoiler syntax wrong the first two times.